# Paas Multiple values to a single parameter at once useing SP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created a procedure to input value and filter information from `Inventory_view_03` table and insert those data in to `Trn_note_header` but procedure is running properly.

When I insert one one value to the input if I enter two or more i doesn't work, but doesn't showing erros.

Can you tell me what was the problem?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertrecord
@KITITEM Varchar(20) 
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @LASTNO int
IF (@LASTNO IS NULL) OR (LEN(@LASTNO) > 0)
BEGIN
  SET @LASTNO= 0
END


SELECT @LASTNO=ISNUMERIC([Trn_number])from [dbo].[Trn_note_header]
SET @LASTNO=@LASTNO+1

insert into[dbo].[Trn_note_header]([Trn_number],[kit_number],[Supplier],[Season],[Pcs])
select @LASTNO,[trb_kit_desc],[shortname],[se_name],[Expr1] From[dbo].[Inventory_view_03]
WHERE trb_kit_desc IN(@KITITEM)

End
```

Comment: If you sql client supports it, you better use a table valued parameter.

Comment: Slighty off-topic: you can replace the line starting `DECLARE @LASTNO...` and the 4 that follow it with 'DECLARE @LASTNO INT = 0;`.  This will achieve the same result.  Also I'm not sure ISNUMERIC is doing what you want it to.

Comment: Hi Thanks For the Help If i want to Get Last Number From Database coloum and increse it from 1 and then i want to insert it so How can i insert that part to this query

Answer (score 0):

when you enter  one,input looks like this

```
trb_kit_desc IN('a')
```

when you enter two or more,input looks like this

```
 trb_kit_desc IN('a,b,c')
```

There is no value matching your query,thats the reason ,it doesn't work..

You can change your insert like below ,to work even in case of mutiple values,you have to split those values using one of the functions from here:https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

```
;with cte
as
(
select * from dbo.split_strings(@KITITEM,',')
)
insert into[dbo].[Trn_note_header]([Trn_number],[kit_number],[Supplier],[Season],[Pcs])
select @LASTNO,[trb_kit_desc],[shortname],[se_name],[Expr1] From[dbo].[Inventory_view_03]
WHERE trb_kit_desc IN(select item from cte)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build dynamic T-SQL statement and executed it. For example:

- you can build the statement as string like this:

  ```
  DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @DynamicSQLStatement = 'insert into[dbo].[Trn_note_header]([Trn_number],[kit_number],[Supplier],[Season],[Pcs])
  select ' + CAST(@LASTNO AS VARCHAR(12)) + ',[trb_kit_desc],[shortname],[se_name],[Expr1] From[dbo].[Inventory_view_03]
  WHERE trb_kit_desc IN(''' + REPLACE(@KITITEM, ',', ''',''')  +''')';

  EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement
  ```
- you can pass the variables to the `sp_executesql` procedure like this:

  ```
  DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @KITITEM = REPLACE(@KITITEM, ',', ''',''');

  SET @DynamicSQLStatement = 'insert into[dbo].[Trn_note_header]([Trn_number],[kit_number],[Supplier],[Season],[Pcs])
  select ' + CAST(@LASTNO AS VARCHAR(12)) + ',[trb_kit_desc],[shortname],[se_name],[Expr1] From[dbo].[Inventory_view_03]
  WHERE trb_kit_desc IN(''@KITITEM'')';

  EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatementN, '@KITITEM Varchar(20), @LASTNO INT', @KITITEM, @LASTNO;
  ```

Anyway, this is alternative,but if I were you I would use the solution with the splinting values of @TheGameiswar.